# ¿Como modifico esta función, que retorna coordenadas para un buscaminas?

Tags: python, string, lista, funciones, bucles

Estoy haciendo un buscaminas donde las posiciones de las minas deben crearse de forma aleatoria, para lo que cree una función, la regla de las minas es que no pueden repetirse!, pero es lo que me esta pasando con esta función

```
from random import randint
import random

# Funcion para crear minas aleatorias    
def minas_alea(cant_de_minas,dimension):
    l = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
    minas = []
    for i in range(cant_de_minas):
        if i not in minas:
            minas.append(random.choice(l) + str(randint(1,dimension)))          
    return minas
```

La función recibe la cantidad de minas, 5 coordenadas de formato `A1`, `B3`, etc y la dimensión del tablero de juego (para que no cree coordenadas fuera del limite del tablero). El error de la función está en que a veces agrega coordenadas repetidas a la lista `minas`. Si alguien pudiera ayudarme seria genial!

Comment: Usar "l" como nombre de variable es mala idea. Se confunde fácilmente con "1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo te falta revisar que la mina candidata no esté dentro de la lista generada.

Con una pequeña modificación queda así:

```
from random import randint
import random

def minas_alea(cant_de_minas,dimension):
    l = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J',
    'K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']

    minas = []

    for i in range(cant_de_minas):
        while True:
            candidata = random.choice(l) +  str(randint(1,dimension))
            if candidata not in minas:
                minas.append(candidata)
                break
            else:
                print("candidata %s rechazada" % candidata)
    return minas
```

La idea es entrar en un ciclo eterno generando minas candidatas en forma aleatoria. Dentro del ciclo revisas que la mina candidata no esté dentro de la lista ya generada.

Tan pronto tienes una mina no existente, la guardas y te sales del ciclo.

Le agregue un "print" para que veas cuando rechaza minas repetidas.

**Edit**

La línea `if i not in minas:` es siempre True, por lo que es innecesaria y la elimine en esta edición.

Minas contiene valores del formato Letra-Digito ('A1', 'M3', ...), mientras que "i" es un entero. Por tanto, "i" nunca estará en "minas".

Comment: Buena!!!, muchas gracias!!! ahí funciona correctamente

Comment: y gracias por aclarar lo del "i" en el ciclo "for"